# iTerm Prev/Next Tab key command to match Safari (Cmd+Shift+[ or ])

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm

Using hex code 0x5b and 0x5d I can get Cmd+[ and Cmd+] to map to prev/next tab but when I click the checkbox to add Shift into the mix, the shortcut does nothing. Any workarounds or secret tips to get this working? I'm about to pull out my hair. (Also, Cmd+0x7b/d -- { and } -- don't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it looks like iTerm (hosted at SourceForge) has been abandoned (as of December 2010). I downloaded [iTerm2](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) (a fork of that codebase) and wouldn't you know, the default prev/next tab key bindings are Cmd+Shift+[ and ]. Hurray.